# Finding the rank of the word MOTHER

Tags: combinatorics

If all the letters of the word MOTHER are shuffled to form all all possible 6-letter words and these words are written in a dictionary order, What could be the index of the word MOTHER in the dictionary?

So the dictionary starts EHMORT, EHMOTR, EHMROT, ...

Comment: What is a positive word?

Comment: What do "alphabets", "positive" and "rank" mean?

Comment: Be more specific. Is MTH in the dictionary, for example, or does the dictionary only consist of words containing all six letters.

Comment: I'm guessing: by "alphabets" OP means "letters." The "rank" is the order of the word in the dictionary of all shuffles of the letters in MOTHER. Have no guess what is intended by "positive," however.

Comment: @TAndrews you are right,positive means possible in this context.My work gave me 309 and 308 but which one could be correct

Answer (score 5):

There are two letters before M, so there are $2\cdot 5!$ arrangements that are before MOTHER in the first letter.

There are two letters other than M before O, so there are $2\cdot 4!$ word starting with $M$ and a letter before O.

There are three letters amongst HER that are before T, so there are $3\cdot 3!$ different words that start with MO and with third letter before T.

There is one letter amongst ER that is before H, so there are $1\cdot 2!$ words beginning with MOT and with next letter before H.

There are no words starting with MOTH and with fourth letter before E.

So that means that there are $2\cdot 5!+2\cdot 4!+3\cdot 3!+1\cdot 2!$ before MOTHER, so the index of MOTHER is one more than that: $2\cdot 5!+2\cdot 4!+3\cdot 3!+1\cdot 2!+1$.

This is making a lot of assumptions about what you mean by your question.

Comment: Thomas Andrews I salute you,I think I was simply suppose to add 1.1! to my answer 308.God bless you abundantly,you have just opened up my mind.

Answer (score 0):

(i) Arrange all the alphabets of word MOTHER in alphabetical order like [E, H, M, O, R, T]
Now, strike off the first letter M from [E, H, M, O, R, T]
Then count the no. of letter be fore M, and it is equal to 2, which 5!
Now, net word O,
Then, count the no. of letter before O and it is equal to 2, which is coefficient of 4!
Next letter T → 3!
Next letter H → 2!
and nett letter E → 1!
So, Rank of the word is
=2(5!)+2(4!)+3(3!)+1(2!)+0(1!)+1
=240+28+18+2+1
=309
word MOTHER is 309.